# How to use the % sign with a variable in graphql query

Tags: javascript, graphql, hasura

I have a query where I want to filter results by seeing what is LIKE the input variable that the user will type.

Here is my query

```
query MyQuery($domain:String!, $hash:String!) {
  hashtags_hashtags(where: {domain: {_eq: $domain}}, limit: 15, offset: 5, order_by: {hashtag: asc}) {
    hashtag
    responses_languages(where: {language: {_eq: "english"}, hashtag: {_ilike: %$hash%}}) {
      hashtag
      response
    }
  }
}
```

So When i was testing the **_ilike** filter in hasura console it only works with a sting written like this ex. "%cheese%". The percent signs work well with the string but when I try to do the same thing with my variable **$hash** it doesn't work. How to do the _ilike with a variable?? Of course I put the $hash after _ilike without the % but it did not return anything. It only works if I use a regular string not a variable. How am I suppose to write _ilike + variable in Hasura graph Ql. Oh and my project is in Javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Query 'body' is not for any kind of operations, no concatenation, no evaluation, no string literals etc.

You must pass ready, prepared earlier, string as variable.

```
variables: {
  domain: "some domain",
  hash: `%${someHashVariable}%`
}

// in query simply 
// ...  hashtag: {_ilike: $hash}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I did this but i still get an error. super strange as this should definitely work

Comment: 100% my fault it is something else in the code. Thanks!

Comment: The issue is that the data is being loaded in as a promise this is a different question but how can I async call my query so that the data can be loaded properly?

Comment: this.$apollo
        .query({
          query: hashQuery,
          variables: {
            domain: this.selectedDomain,
            hash:`$%{this.searchedHash}%`
        
          }
        })
        .then(({ data }: any) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data.hashtags_hashtags))

          this.hashtags = data.hashtags_hashtags
         
        })

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem, but my problem is how can I use this on REST API URL params? Can you check it? Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69938925/searching-string-using-dynamic-variable-on-graphql-hasura

Comment: @AkoSi not a graphql problem .... google/look for "url encoding special chars" in GET method paraps context