# Searching string using dynamic variable on GraphQL Hasura

Tags: graphql, hasura

Im new to GraphQL and Hasura, i need to create a REST API Endpoint using an existing graphql query. Im having a hard time on passing a string variables for a search function.I need to pass the variable with "%" on the beginning and ending of the string.

I have this query

```
    query MyQuery($category_title: String, $search_title: String, $offset: Int, $limit: Int) {
  products(order_by: {created_at: desc}, where: {_or: {description: {_ilike: $search_title}}, category_title: {_ilike: $category_title}}, offset: $offset, limit: $limit) {
    id
    available
    category_title
    description
    title
    sku
    images(where: {related_type: {_eq: "products"}}) {
      id
      file {
        id
        url
      }
    }
    variant_object: components(where: {field: {_eq: "variants"}}) {
      variant {
        id
        quantity
        sku
        title
        price: components(where: {field: {_eq: "price"}}) {
          money {
            amount
            currency
            id
            precision
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And created the REST API ENDPOINT like this:

```
https://xxxxx.hasura.app/api/rest/test/:category_title/:search_title/:offset/:limit
```

This is what im thinking that will work but its not, also If i want to pass null value.

```
https://xxxxx.hasura.app/api/rest/test/%%/%title%/0/10
```

Then use this as URL params, it works but in some search string, it will give me results but some search key gives me a "Internal Server Error" on reqbin.com

```
https://xxxxxx.hasura.app/api/rest/products?category_title=%$category_title%&search_title=%$search_title%&offset=0
```

I know im doing it wrong, can someone help me, i need to search a string but allow a null value on category and search title. Basically im using it for product listing and search page.

Thanks!

Comment: not a graphql problem, read about url encoding - params, spaces, special chars